# Find and remove enum value from array

Tags: solidity

I have an array of enums that I push to. I would like to work out how to remove a specific enum value from the array but I'm not having much luck finding the index for deletion:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

ErrorCode[] errors;

// Add to array
errors.push(ErrorCode.A);
errors.push(ErrorCode.B);
errors.push(ErrorCode.C);

// Find and delete ErrorCode.B;
uint index = errors[ErrorCode.B].index;
delete errors[index];
```

I assumed the above would give me the index of the array but it does not. The compiler errors tells me `Type enum Security.ErrorCode is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.`

Any guidance would be much appreciated.